# ESXI 5.5 NFS to NFS copy is slow

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage, netapp, synology

i'm running esxi 5.5u2 standalone with 3 datastores , (local , netapp (nfs) and synology (nfs )

There are two Gigabit network adapters configured. One per vswitch.

One for storage and the other for management. the two adapter and Nas are on the same physical switch.

i want to copy a vm from the netapp to the synology but the speed is very slow (8 -10 MB /sec) instead of 30 - 60 MB /sec

Individual test show speed topping at 60 MB sec

Where is the bottleneck and how to avoid it?

(see the following performance graph to understand.)

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a clue .

the two cards were on separate vswitch and i tested also the card in the same vswitch and assigning a vmnic to each portgroup.

It looks like if i want to force read on vmnic0 and write on vmnic1 to maximize bandwidth something is slowing it down.

[image]

Now if i put all vmnic on the same vswitch (separate port group) and default network failover order, vmware use one adapter to read and write  and this is faster.
[image]

Yet i have to find the reason for this behavior .

To be continued ...